# match an object in an array of objects and remove

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

After 2 days of fighting this problem I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have two arrays of objects, like this:

```
let oldRecords = [
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'ringo'}
];

let newRecords = [
  {name: 'paul'},
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'stuart'}
];
```

I am trying to end up with a function that returns named variables containing a list of data thats been added (exist in `newRecords` but not in `oldRecords`) and a list of data that has been removed (exists in `oldRecords` but not in `newRecords`).

for example

```
const analyse = (older, newer) => {
  let added, removed;
    // ... magic
  return {added, removed}
}

const {added, removed} = analyse(oldRecords, newRecords);
```

I won't post all the code I've tried inside this function as I have tried to map, reduce and loop through both arrays creating temporary arrays for the last 48 hours and I could now fill a book with code I've written and deleted. I have also used underscore.js methods like `reject`/`find`/`findWhere` which all got me close but no cigar.

the main issue I am having is because the arrays contain objects, its super easy if they contain numbers, i.e.

```
var oldRecords = [1, 3];
var newRecords = [1, 2, 4]

function analyse (old, newer) { 
  let added = [];
  let removed = [];

  old.reduce((o) => {
    added = added.concat(_.reject(newer, (num) => num === o ));
  });

  newer.reduce((n) => {
    removed = _.reject(old, (num) => num === n );
  });

  return {added, removed}
}

const {added, removed} = analyse(oldRecords, newRecords);
```

How can I achieve the above but with objects not arrays?

n.b. I tried modifying the above and using `JSON.stringify` but it didn't really work.

**EDIT**: important point I forgot to add, the object structure adn it's `keys` are dynamic, they come from a database, so any individual checking of a `key` must also be dynamic, i.e. not a hard coded value

Comment: Can you just check object by name, or you need to check full object?

Comment: good point and made me realise I'd forgotten a very important restriction. the object keys are dynamic, so although they will all have the same keys, the keys themselfs come from a database and so can/will change. so can't hard code them. it's one of the reasons I'm finding this a tricky one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**reject**](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) and [**some**](http://underscorejs.org/#some) to check for inclusion in the appropriate sets. The [**isEqual**](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) function is used to check for equality to handle dynamic keys:

```
const analyse = (older, newer) => {
  let added = _.reject(newer, n => _.some(older, o =>_.isEqual(n, o)));
  let removed = _.reject(older, o => _.some(newer, n => _.isEqual(n, o)));

  return {added, removed}
}
```

Comment: thanks, looks really good. what would you suggest Re: the object keys being dynamic. i.e. the object might not have a `name` key. these are annoyingly set in a database, which a user will change.

Comment: Changed the predicate to use `isEqual`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
const analyse = (older, newer) => {
   let removed = older.filter(newItem => {
     return newer.filter(oldItem => {
        return _.isEqual(newItem, oldItem);
     }).length === 0
   });

   let added = newer.filter(oldItem => {
     return older.filter(newItem => {
        return _.isEqual(newItem, oldItem);
     }).length === 0
   });

   return {added, removed};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create function to check if two object are equal, end then use `filter()` and `some()` to return result.

```js
let oldRecords = [
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'ringo'}
];

let newRecords = [
  {name: 'paul'},
  {name: 'john'},
  {name: 'stuart'}
];


function isEqual(o1, o2) {
  return Object.keys(o1).length == Object.keys(o2).length &&
    Object.keys(o1).every(function(key) {
      return o2.hasOwnProperty(key) && o1[key] == o2[key]
    })
}

var result = {}
result.removed = oldRecords.filter(e => !newRecords.some(a => isEqual(e, a)))
result.added = newRecords.filter(e => !oldRecords.some(a => isEqual(e, a)))
console.log(result)
```